# Как сделать треугольную стрелочку внизу рамки на css?

Tags: css, css3

Пытаюсь сделать рамку со стрелочкой сниуз как на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Замучался.  не получается..

```css
.block {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
}

.block span.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: auto;
  right: 17%;
  border-top: 30px solid #fff;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
}

.block span.triangle:before {
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 45px;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.block span.triangle:after {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  some text
  <span class="triangle"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.block {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
}

.block:after {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -16px;
  right: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  some text
  <span class="triangle"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Как например с помощью псевдоэлементов и треугольников:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
}

.block:before,
.block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.block:before {  
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
  border-top: 32px solid #aaa;
  right: 29px;
  bottom: -32px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block:after {  
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid #fff;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: -29px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi vitae nemo aut quisquam incidunt mollitia provident rerum doloribus doloremque dolorem!
</div>
```